# FIX Protocol with Ruby (and Rails)

Tags: ruby, protocols, fix-protocol

Trying to use FIX Protocol (FIX4.4) to get stock market prices using Ruby. I'd like it to be on Rails too but simplifying things first.

I have the following code:

```
host_name = TCPSocket.gethostbyname(ADDRESS) # Not needed but checking resolves to IPa ddress
something = TCPSocket.new(ADDRESS, PORT)
```

However I am getting:

```
<#to_s method raised exception: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)>
```

As the value of 'something'. Is there anyone that can give me a clue as to what is going on?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: With all due respect, this is not a good way to approach your task.  FIX isn't *super* complicated, but it's complex enough that you should really seek out a FIX engine with a Ruby interface.  I highly recommend that you demo out a few.  (I'm most familiar with QuickFIX variants, but there's no native Ruby impl, just a Ruby wrapper around C++.   Maybe check out some Ruby native ones.)

Comment: A ruby-only option might be the [fix-engine](https://rubygems.org/gems/fix-engine) gem. Last updated in 2015, so proceed with caution.

Comment: I've started looking into the available engines. QuickFIX does look promising. fix-engine does also look promising. Does look as if it might not be maintained. But being in Ruby, I'll probably be able to get my head around it and update as needed. for example it does not seem to support passwords?!?!?!?

Answer (score 1):

I think your quickest / cheapest / easiest (already tested etc) solution if you want a FIX engine is to use QuickFIXJ to connect to your FIX counterparties and to work your FIX messaging layer. If you're not using middleware (I like Apache Geode since it's now open source. You could [integrate with Ruby via the REST interface](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/10/rest_apps/rest_examples.html)) then you can persist the FIX layer direct to your DB, and use Ruby on Rails to read it back to your UI layer. The DB needs to keep up with the market. If you've got a fast market with many updates per second you may find the DB falling behind: market makers all use RV, Gemfire, MQ etc. before persistence to their databases.